# ElasticSearch Nest Flags c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, flags, nest

Basicly I have a flag field similar to this

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags
{
   FirstFlag = 1,
   SecondFlag = 2
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public MyFlags MyFlagProperty { get; set; }
}

Client.Search<T, TResult>(c=>c.Query ??? )
```

My problem here is that I cant find any way to search for entries where only my FirstFlag is required. Am I approaching this wrong? Should I use 2 properties instead?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool MyFirstFlag { get; set; }
    public bool MySecondFlag { get; set; }
}

Client.Search<T, TResult>(c => c.Query(d => d.Term("MyFirstFlag", true)));
```

What is the best approach here? Would you recommend to not use flags at all and just go by properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches you could take here

1. Make the property a set of enum values
2. Use a custom `JsonConverter` to serialize an enum with the `FlagsAttribute` to a collection and deserialize a collection to an enum
3. Have separate properties as you have suggested

I'd personally choose number 2 as it will allow you to work with the enum as is in code, yet store the field as a collection in Elasticsearch and easily query it.